# pre_get_posts gives 404 error on Custom Post

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, 404-error, pre-get-posts

I know this has been covered in different ways a thousand times (I read all the posts), but it seems not specifically for my case. I can't really get it to work myself, being a big development noobie.

I have a template which shows the last posts on the front page. I changed the type of posts shown to `question` (my website is a Q&A one) but then pagination was only showing 13 pages while there are 29 pages of questions. 13 pages being the number of non-custom-type normal posts. 
So I added this code in `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function($q) { 
    if( !is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() && !$q->is_tax() ) { 
        $q->set ('post_type', array( 'question' ) ); 
    } 
});
```

Now it counts the number of Questions correctly but it throws a 404 error every time I click on the link to a question. I understand that `pre_get_posts` is not the best approach, but I really don't know how to change it and use `WP_Query` instead, as I saw was advised to.

Any fix to that ? Thank you <3

Answer (score 0):

This might be a quick fix for your custom post type 404 error page.

> Navigate to **Settings** > **Permalinks**, and then click the **Save Changes** button.

Then comeback to check if the links doesn't give you a 404 error.

Comment: Already tried that, doesn't change anything but ty :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's the front page query, then you should check for that case instead of `!$q->is_tax()`, which will be true in lots of cases other than the front page.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function($q) { 
    if( !is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() && $q->is_front_page() ) {
        $q->set ('post_type', array( 'articles' ) ); 
    } 
});
```

and `pre_get_posts` is indeed the correct way to handle this sort of thing, running an additional query with `WP_Query` would just waste server resources.

Comment: Thanks really a lot Milo !! I actually changed it to : `add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function($q) { 
if( !is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() && !$q->is_tax() && $q->is_front_page() ) { 
$q->set ('post_type', array( 'question' ) ); 
} 
}); `  And now it works both for pagination and single CPT  :D :D